# Creat custom reusable Alert (or Modal) component with Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an alert that has some startup and other logic attached which I would like to reuse in multiple places inside my app.

My current solution which I do not like is that I have a component which on construction creates and presents the alert.
so when I want the alert to show up I have to push my new component onto the stack which then results in the alert showing up.  On alert cancel or action, I pop my new component off of the stack and it returns to the previous view.

The problem is that a white screen appears before the alert and then disappears, so the alert isn't really being shown on top of the correct view.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is create a service then import that service into any component that you want to use the alert in. I did this recently with an Ionic2 application. Something like this should work nicely.

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class AlertLoader {

  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController){}

  complexAlert(title, subTitle, buttonObj){
    let Alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: title,
    subTitle: subTitle,
    buttons: buttonObj
    })
    console.log(Alert);
    Alert.present();
  }

}
```

and then to use it in your component, import it and call it like so. Dont forget to add it to your constructor though!

```
this.alertLoader.complexAlert('Title', 'subtitle', buttonObj)
```

you can hardcode that information if it will be constant or include it in another file and import it if you wish to use the alert elsewhere.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting...It looks like this would accomplish what I want to from the UX perspective but makes me wonder if there is a better way to do it.  Requiring a service for custom alerts/modals doesn't seem like the best design choice.

Comment: You might have a general services file that you reference, you could include it in that so you minimize the imports but I havent really discovered an easier way to make it versatile. If you find one, please post it here so I can see! :)

Comment: another solution has been suggested here with reasoning as why the service layer should not interact with the view layer https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/creat-custom-reusable-alert-or-modal-component/76539/2

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**in Ionic 5 we can use share module :

[share modals example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PYjZ.png)

**1/ create SharedModule and Declare and exports Modals you want to share**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { PrItemPage } from 'src/app/purchase/purchase-request/modals/pr-item/pr-item.page';
import { PrItemSelectPage } from 'src/app/purchase/purchase-request/modals/pr-item-select/pr-item-select.page';
import { PrSelectPage } from 'src/app/purchase/purchase-request/modals/pr-select/pr-select.page';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PrItemPage,
    PrItemSelectPage,
    PrSelectPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    PrItemPage,
    PrItemSelectPage,
    PrSelectPage,
  ]
})
export class SharedPRModalModule { }
```

**2 Let import ShareModule to PageModule you want to reuse**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { PurchaseorderMaintainPage } from './purchaseorder-maintain.page';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';
import { PurchaseRequestMaintainPageModule } from '../../purchase-request/purchase-request-maintain/purchase-request-maintain.module';
import { SharedPRModalModule } from 'src/app/_modals/shared-pr-modal/shared-pr-modal.module';
import { PrSelectPage } from '../../purchase-request/modals/pr-select/pr-select.page';
import { PrItemSelectPage } from '../../purchase-request/modals/pr-item-select/pr-item-select.page';
import { PrItemPage } from '../../purchase-request/modals/pr-item/pr-item.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PurchaseorderMaintainPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SharedPRModalModule
  ],
  providers: [
    BarcodeScanner
  ],
  declarations: [PurchaseorderMaintainPage],
  entryComponents: [PrSelectPage, PrItemSelectPage, PrItemPage],
})
export class PurchaseorderMaintainPageModule {}
```